# get data from pc

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access, ubuntu-12.04

I have a little problem I need to solve probably easy and here is the setup:

There is PC »A« (windows7) with data I need at location »L1« and PC »B« (Ubuntu 12.04) at location »L2«.

»L1« and »L2« are very distant to each other, so going from »L1« to »L2« or back is not possible for me.

I am at »L2« and I can phone somebody at »L1« to instruct this person what to do to make me access PC »A« via network. But the person at »L1« wont be very skilled in computer stuff, so instructions have to be simple. If possible I would like to avoid to instruct this person to setup a port forwarding on the router and setup a dyndns, what i possibly could do if I had the ip of the router.

So my question is:

What is the most clever approach, which software to use? Best thing would be if I could access PC »A« via ssh, but because this is windows that could be complicated. Priority one is: easy setup.

Thanks for any help!!!

Greetings philipp

Comment: Do you or the person at «L1» have access to any desktop sharing utilities?

Comment: Use teamviewer to control PC A yourself. Then install a FTP server so you can use a FTP client whenever you need files.

Comment: @Martin so if I can mange to make the person at »L1« make successfully install teamviewer, I can gain all the control of PC »A«?

Comment: Teamviewer does not even require any installation. The setup asks if you would like to install the product, or run it right away without installing. By the way, teamviewer also supports file transfer.